# how to reduce if and elif with in a single statement based on two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can we make everything in single if condition by handling c1 and c2 not equals to zero

```
def func(self):
        c1 = self.x.getc1()
        c2 = self.x.getc2()

        if c1 != 0:
            cost = getcod(c1)
            price = round(float(cost), 2)
            return price
        elif (c2 != 0):

            cost = getcod(c2)
            price = round(float(cost), 2)

            return price
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the two methods.

```
for m in [self.x.getc1, self.x.getc2]:
    c = m()
    if c != 0:
        cost = getcod(c)
        price = round(float(cost), 2)
        return price
```

If the loop terminates without returning, `None` will be implicitly returned, or you can add `return None` explicitly after the loop.

The first non-zero value, as in the original, will cause the function to return early from inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Single-line solution -> ternary operator. But it would make the code less readable.

Instead, you can assign first non-zero c1/c2 value and have one if:

```
def func(self):
        c = self.x.getc1() or self.x.getc2() #boolean value of 0 is False
        if c!= 0:
            cost = getcod(c)
            price = round(float(cost), 2)
            return price
        return None
```

The trick here is boolean value an how `or` works:

- boolean value of 0 is False, boolean value of any other number is True;
- `or` is a logical operator and needs only one element to be True, so it returns first True element (or in case of all False elements, returns the last one)

This trick is used to easily create default/alternative values for when something might be 0/empty (empty lists, empty strings, empty sets, empty dicts - all "are" False)/None.

PS I kept `return None` here. If your function may return non-None value, it's better to show exactly where it may return None, for better readability and later debugging!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use for loop

```
def func(self):
        data = [self.x.getc1(),self.x.getc2()]
        for i in data:
            if ( i != 0 ):
                cost = getcod(i)
                price = round(float(cost), 2)
                return price
        return None
```